# initialize with pharo smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Here is a description of my problem. I have a Person class which has three attributes: lastname, name and birthDate.

```
Object subclass: #Person
    instanceVariableNames: 'name lastName birthDate'
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'Moi'
```

i have the setters:

```
name: aString
  name := aString
```

and similarly for `birthDate` and `lastName`.

For this class, i have a constructor:

```
Person class >> withName: aName birthDate: aDate lastName: aLastName
  | person |
  person := self new.
  person
    name: aName;
    birthDate: aDate;
    lastName: aLastName.
  ^person
```

To create an instance of a class i send `new` to the class:

```
person := Person new
```

Then, i provide values to its ivars:

```
person name: 'toto'; birthDate: '13 Sep 2022'; lastName: 'tata'
```

Now, I'm not going to have the user enter the method values ​​himself

```
Person>>#withName:andBirthDate:andLastName:
```

For this I wrote a method generateData which takes between a method and generates the values ​​that the method receives as arguments. i call it like this in my playground:

```
generateData:Person>>#withName:andBirthDate:andLastName:
```

once inside the method, I start by retrieving the instance variables of the class via:

```
iVars := aMethod variableWriteNodes.
    (iVars collect: [ :i | myAllInstVars add:i name ]).
```

at the end, myAllInstVars has all the instance variables of the class where the method has been implemented. now i am generating random value for each variable based on its type. to do it, i do this:

```
 resultTypeVariables collect: [ :i | 
        (i isFloat ) ifTrue: [ items add: ((1 to: 1000) atRandom asFloat) ].
        (i = SmallInteger) ifTrue: [ items add:(1 to: 256) atRandom ]. 
        (i isInteger) ifTrue: [ items add:(1 to: 256) atRandom ].
        (i isNumber) ifTrue: [ items add:(1 to: 256) atRandom ].
        (i isString )       ifTrue: [ items add:UUID new asString36].
        (i == ByteString ) ifTrue: [ items add:UUID new asString36].
        (i == Date) ifTrue: [ items add:(Date fromDays: (1 to: 36000)atRandom) ].
          ].
```

items contains the generated values.
This is where my problem begins.
I would like to rebuild the Person>>#withName:andBirthDate:andLastName: method by adding in its signature the values ​​contained in items.

here is the idea i implemented. I retrieve the setters in the setter protocol like this:

```
setter := classMethod allSelectorsInProtocol: #'setter'.
    ( setter ) do: [:i|
    instObject := setter,':',items.
    ].
```

but when i return instObject i get this as result:
[image]

I don't know what to do right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the part you are missing here is the `#perform:` family of messages. They transform selectors into messages as follows

```
person := Person new.
person perform: #name: withArgument: 'toto'
```

where `#perform:with:` builds the message with selector `#name:` and argument `'toto'`. While there are variants for any number of arguments, what you need is the one I just described.

Thus, if you have say `ivars := #('toto' '12 Sep 2022' 'tata')` you will be done with

```
setters with: ivars do: [:setter :ivar | person perform: setter with: ivar]
```

where `setters := #(#name: #birthDate: #lastName:)`.

Given that in your case `#allSelectorsInProtocol:` collects the selectors in a `Set`, you might want to put them in an `Array` instead and sort them alphabetically for indentification:

```
(class allSelectorsInProtocol: #setters) asArray sorted
```

which will produce `#(#birthDate: #lastName: #name:)`. Note also that this will require collecting your data in the same order so to match the arguments.

Comment: Hello Sir, in fact I know how to instantiate a class and insert the values as you did. but I would like to do that in a method through the source code without going through a user.

Comment: here's the idea I have. I created a "setter" protocol inside which I put all the setters. And in the code, I have a collection in which, I put the generated values.
now I wanted to make a concatenation between the setters and the values generated according to the signature of the method to instantiate the class in question. that's kinda where my problem lies.

Comment: OK. Then edit your question and add this information and we will try to help you better. An example of the "generated" collection you envision would be useful too.

Comment: do you have any idea to suggest me ?

Comment: I spent almost three weeks thinking about it

Comment: I might. Problem is that I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. So, instead of guessing I would prefer to understand your question better.

Comment: I just edited my post. sorry for editing your answer too soon. I didn't pay attention.

Comment: That's OK. I've replaced the entire answer. Let me know if it's now of any help.

Comment: i have this message when i execute my method: Instance of Set did not understand #with:do:

Comment: `Set`s are not sequenceable. Collect your data in an `OrderedCollection` instead.

Comment: because my setter return this: a Set [3 items] (#lastName: #name: #birthDate:)

Comment: this message return a Set

**classMethod allSelectorsInProtocol: #'setter'**

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Leandro It's alright It works. But I removed sorted

Comment: You shouldn't remove `sorted`. Sets produce different orderings when converted to arrays in ways that are usually unpredictable, i.e., random, meaning that the same set could produce an sequence now and another in the future.