# Stream assigment in pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a problem here.

I have a `data` variable of type `an OrderedCollection`.

this variable shows me this when I do a DoIt: `an OrderedCollection ('3c7lwmdva2b8jbt39ls4pz3sl' '3c7lwmbf36tamw1m45riirdze' 8 February 1994)`.

Now I would like this:

```
object:=String streamContents:
    [:stream|
    stream
    nextPutAll: 'data:= ';cr;
    print:data asArray.]
```

But when I run, it shows me this:

```
data := an Array End of statement list encounteencountered -> ('3c7lwmdva2b8jbt39ls4pz3sl' '3c7lwmbf36tamw1m45riirdze' 8 February 1994).
```

So month I wanted to get this:

```
data := #('3c7lwmdva2b8jbt39ls4pz3sl' '3c7lwmbf36tamw1m45riirdze' 8 February 1994).
```

How to do please?

Comment: Are you missing a close bracket to show the end of the block? Do you intend to have a line break after the assignment string?

Comment: I came to édit the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result := String streamContents: [:stream |
  stream nextPutAll: 'data := #('.
  data
    do: [:string | stream nextPut: $'; nextPutAll: string asString; nextPut: $']
    separatedBy: [stream space].
  stream nextPut: $)]
```

Since my answer has been downvoted, I'll explain the solution.

1. **What's in `data`?** The question says that `data` prints as (original formatting, sorry about that)

```
an OrderedCollection ('3c7lwmdva2b8jbt39ls4pz3sl' '3c7lwmbf36tamw1m45riirdze' 8 February 1994).
```

which indicates that `data` is an `OrderedCollection` with two strings and a `Date`.

2. **What is the OP trying to compute?** It is not clear. The use of `String streamContents:` seems to indicate that the OP is trying to produce a `String`, more precisely an assignment sentence where `data` is assigned the `OrderedCollection` converted to an `Array`.
3. **Solution to 2.** Assuming my guess in 2 is right, my code above produces such a sentence.
4. **What other interpretation can we give to this unclear question?**
   Well, may be the OP is just looking for a method that would convert the `OrderedCollection` into an `Array`. In this case, the answer would have been simply

```
object := data asArray.
```

However, given a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73996743/4081336), where the same OP was trying to do some metaprogramming, the actual intention remains unclear.

Comment: When I apply what you say, I get this error: `Instance of Date did not understand #do:`

Comment: You are right, I didn't pay attention to the fact that one of the entries was a `Date`. I've update the code, please try again.

Comment: i have this: 

`data := 'bpuj19rdgb0qu4r0hu23w9clz' End of statement list encountered -> 'bpuj19m6yaq10wu4nf1jkkr6x' '23 October 1978'an OrderedCollection('bpuj19rdgb0qu4r0hu23w9clz' 'bpuj19m6yaq10wu4nf1jkkr6x' 23 October 1978).`

Comment: I had forgotten the parentheses.

Comment: I modified but I have this 
`data:= #('2i43mh7756bf8y2xqeaqdoc21' '2i43mhb7czl35dwr67z9diu7a' '25 February 1993'an OrderedCollection('2i43mh7756bf8y2xqeaqdoc21' '2i43mhb7czl35dwr67z9diu7a' 25 February 1993)).`

but I would like to have this: 
`data := #('2i43mh7756bf8y2xqeaqdoc21' '2i43mhb7czl35dwr67z9diu7a' '25 February 1993')`

Comment: That's probably because you're assigning to `result` directly whatever is returned by `#streamContents:`. I don't have access to a Pharo instance right now, but I think your `#asArray` approach was the right idea, Mansour. What does `asArray printString` give you? Also, Leandro, please don't use `strm` as a variable when you can use `stream`. This is Smalltalk!